# Kronecker product with augmented matrices

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

I need to pull out, for example, row 2 of a matrix, but never add the elements in a row, so I believe a Kronecker product involving an augmented matrix containing identity matrices is required.  The operation would be something like the following:

$ \pmatrix{
x_{12} & x_{12}\cr
x_{21} & x_{22}\cr
x_{31} & x_{32}\cr
x_{41} & x_{42}\cr
}  \otimes \pmatrix{
\bf{A} & \bf{B} & \bf{C} & \bf{D}\cr
\bf{E} & \bf{F} & \bf{G} & \bf{H}\cr
} = \{x_{21}, x_{22}\}$

The resulting matrix needs to contain only a single copy of $x_{21}$ and a single copy of $x_{22}$ with all other elements equal to zero. (NB: I am using the set of elements in row 2, $\{x_{21}, x_{22}\}$, to denote one copy of each in the final matrix).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I didn't get you wrong! You should do it by multiplying from left:

$\left( \begin{matrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{x}_{11}} & {{x}_{12}}  \\
   {{x}_{21}} & {{x}_{22}}  \\
   {{x}_{31}} & {{x}_{32}}  \\
   {{x}_{41}} & {{x}_{42}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{x}_{21}} & {{x}_{22}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$